# CosmosDB - Querying Across All Partitions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning

I'm creating a logging system to monitor our *(200 ish)* main application installations, and Cosmos db seems like a good fit due to the amount of data we'll collect, and to allow a varying schema for the log data (particularly the `Tags` array - see document schema below).

But, never having used CosmosDb before I'm slightly unsure of what to use for my partition key.

If I partitioned by `CustomerId`, there would likely be several `Gb` of data in each of the 200 partitions, and the data will usually be queried by `CustomerId`, so this was my first choice for the partition key.

However I was planning to have a 'log stream' view in the logging system, showing logs coming in for **all customers**.

- Would this lead to running a horribly slow / expensive cross partition query?

If so, is there an obvious way to avoid / limit the cost & speed implications of this cross partition querying? (Other than just taking out the log stream view for all customers!)

```
{
    "CustomerId": "be806507-7cc4-4db4-881b",
    "CustomerName": "Our Customer",
    "SystemArea": 1,
    "SystemAreaName": "ExchangeSync",
    "Message": "Updated OK",
    "Details": "",
    "LogLevel": 2,
    "Timestamp": "2018-11-23T10:59:29.7548888+00:00",
    "Tags": {
        "appointmentId": "109654",
        "appointmentGroupId": "86675",
        "exchangeId": "AAMkA",
        "exchangeAlias": "customer.name@customer.com"        
    }    
}
```

*(Note - There isn't a defined list of `SystemArea` types we'll use yet, but it would be a lot fewer than the 200 customers)*

Answer (score 1):

Cross partition queries should be avoided as much as possible. If your querying is likely to happen with customer id then the customerid is a good logical partition key. However you have to keep in mind that there is a limit of 10GB per logical partition data.

A cross partition query across the whole database will lead to a very slow and very expensive operation but if it's not functionality critical and it's just used for infrequent reporting, it's not too much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Nick. As I feared, and you say, I guess there's no getting away from querying across all partitions being a bad thing. I suppose this is just a trade off that I need to get my old fashioned relational sql head around...

Comment: @Ted You need to keep in mind that indexing works differently as well. If you only index what you need to query against you can improve your performance even further, but yeah it's a trade-off.

Comment: Do you think a second collection, structured differently, might be a good way around this? Obviously there will be duplicated data stored, but the storage side of things with Cosmos seems cheap compared to the RUs incurred when doing cross partition queries.

Comment: @Ted What I would do is that I would have an Azure Function using Cosmos DB trigger or a microservice using the Change Feed Processor library (which is what the Azure Functions ComsosDB uses behind the scenes) and save all the incoming changes to a different database system of my choice just for querying. That way you don't stress your Cosmos and your aren't limited on RUs or cross partition queries. You could even save it in SQL and query that.

Comment: Heh! I'm in the process of removing the logs (and associated tagged data) from a Azure SQL db and putting them into Cosmos! Querying them via the tagged data was a little slow (Another story, but was hard to index due to the amount of data present, and cost constraints on the db), and from what I read Cosmos seemed perfect for a large dump of data with varying schema. I won't give up just yet, but perhaps I should try again with brute forcing some indexes onto my slow SQL tables...

Comment: I am from the CosmosDB engineering team. Thanks @NickChapsas for your inputs! As he mentioned, one thing to keep in mind is the limit on per-partition key limit of 10GB. If you are OK with that, the changefeed processor could be utilized to get the stream of logs across all customers cheaply (as already discussed).

Comment: I know his thread is a little old but I’m in a very similar boat whereby my most common query is via the partition key bu sometimes might span multiple keys because of a wildcard character. 

Please could our elaborate on both your final solution and the concept of the change feed processor?

Comment: Hi @GavinHill sorry I can't help you more, but in the end I wimped out of using Cosmos and went with SQL instead. With some careful design decisions, the correct DB Indexes and as much in memory caching as possible, I managed to cope OK with the large amount of data. Good luck with your project!